# How to inherit from an Object class in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, object, matrix

I inherit from an Object class, my class clsMatrizDb to handle an Array(,); but when I do it generates the following

```
public objPubMatriz as clsMatrizDb(,)
objPubMatriz (0,0) = 1
```

I get an error saying that you can't convert from integer to clsXArrayDb

My class is inheriting like this

```
Public Class clsMatrizDb
Inherits Object

Private vIntRow As Integer
Private vIntColumn As Integer

Public Sub New()
MyBase.New
Me.vIntRow = 0
Me.vIntColumn = 0
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal pvIntRow As Integer, ByVal pvIntColumn As Integer)
Me.vIntRow = pvIntRow
Me.vIntColumn = pvIntColumn
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm missing something?

Comment: You can remove `Inherits Object` and `MyBase.New()` (maybe replace it with `Me.New(0, 0)`) -- You probably wanted to declare, e.g. `Public objPubMatriz(10, 1) As clsMatrizDb`, then assign an new `clsMatrizDb`, e.g,  `objPubMatriz(0, 0) = New clsMatrizDb(1, 1)` -- You should probably describe what this class is used for, it's easier to suggest something meaningful.

Comment: "my class clsMatrizDb to handle an Array(,)"-Based on this statement and the usage case of `objPubMatriz(0,0)=1`, you may want to declare a "Default Property" (also known as an indexer); i.e. `Default Public Property Index(i As Integer, j As Integer) As Integer`.  See: [How to: Declare and Call a Default Property in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property).  Then you would declare objPubMatriz as `Public objPubMatriz As New clsMatrizDb`.

Comment: I agree with cleaning up. There is no need for Inherits Object. An instance of a class is an Object by default.
2.

Comment: @TnTinMn As I recall, the default name of the indexer in VB is `Item` so that might be preferable for the name of the default property.

Comment: @Craig- I meant to type Item, but typed Index for some reason (getting too old, fatigued).  AFAIK, there is no specific default name other than that Item is what MS used in the framework classes.  They could just as well selected "Member" or "Element" or "Piece" or possibly "Thing"   :).

Comment: thank you, very much, TnTinMn and jimi, you comment too heped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comments ended up too long, so here's my explainer:

I agree with cleaning up comments made.

- There is no need for Inherits Object. An instance of a class is an Object by default.
- The default value of an Integer value is 0 so no need to set this explicitly in the New() sub. If you like, set it explicitly in the variable declarations.
- There is no need to call MyBase.New because you are actually not inheriting from a base/abstract class.

You have stated that the error is converting from integer to clsXArrayDb but you don't mention this class at all. Do you mean clsMatrizDb?

The error you are getting is because you are trying to assign the integer value, 1 to an instance (object) of type clsMatrizDb.

If you want to create an instance of clsMatrizDb with Row and Column values initialised as 0, 0 then you just need to declare:

```
public objPubMatriz as New clsMatrizDb()
```

If you want to create an instance of clsMatrizDb with different Row and Column values (for example 2 and 4) then you would declare:

```
public objPubMatriz as New clsMatrizDb(2,4)
```

To be able to assign an integer value to your clsMatrizDb object, you will either need a default property as described by TnTinMn... which overrides a need for you to have a constructor that takes the Row and Column values. You would code:

```
public objPubMatriz as New clsMatrizDb()
objPubMatriz(2,4) = 1
```

The default property would be declared as:

```
Default Public Property Item(ByVal pvIntRow As Integer, ByVal pvIntColumn As Integer) As Integer
```

and you would set the values for vIntRow and vIntColumn as part of this property implementation.

If you want to keep the parameterised constructor then you will need to add a Value property to the class:

```
public property Value as Integer
```

With usage:

```
public objPubMatriz as New clsMatrizDb(2,4)
objPubMatriz.Value = 1
```

Comment: As I noted above, it might be preferable to use `Item` for the indexer since (as I recall) that is the default name for it in VB (as when consuming an indexer from a C# assembly).

Comment: Thank you very much, Catalina, your comment helped me a lot

Comment: Ok, craig I'll keep it in mind

Comment: Yep. I agree with Craig that if the assignment of 1 is as an indexer then Item should be used instead of Index.